# Particular SQL Query performance improving

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, sql-server-2008

I use Amazon Lambda which has memory limits for proceeding certain actions. And this query retrieving quite a lot of data (~100k+ rows) and running out of those limits.

```
SELECT EE.ID, ILE.Zip AS EventLocationZip, EET.Name as EventType, EE.TypeID as EventTypeID, E.Length, EL.Name as LengthUnit, 
                                        CP.Name as EventPlaceName, EE.FKPlaceID as EventPlaceID, IL.Name as EventLocationName, IL.ID as EventLocationId, 
                                        I.ID as InstituteID, I.Name as InstituteName, I.Email, I.Telephone, I.FAX, ILA.City, ILA.Zip, ILA.Street, ILA.Country,
                                        E.ID as EducationID, E.Name as EducationName, E.Link as EducationLink, CE.Name as EducationTypeName, CE.ID as EducationTypeID, 
                                        ESI.TypeID as EventStartInfoTypeID, ESI.Date as StartDate, ESI.EndDate, ESI.Month, ESI.MonthYear, ESI.FKSemesterID as Semester, ESI.SemesterYear, 
                                        EEP.Vat, EEP.Price, EC.Name as Currency, IP.Value as TextPropertyValue, IP.FKTextPropertyID as TextPropertyID, CPIL.Name AS EventLocationPlaceName, 
                                        CPIL2.Name AS EventLocationPlaceNameParent 
        FROM
            education.EducationEvents EE
            INNER JOIN education.EventStartInfos ESI ON EE.ID = ESI.FKEducationEventID
            INNER JOIN education.EducationEventPrices EEP ON EE.ID = EEP.FKEventID
            INNER JOIN education.TypeOfEvents EET ON EE.TypeID = EET.ID
            LEFT JOIN institute.InstituteLocations IL ON IL.ID = EE.FKLocationID
            LEFT JOIN core.Places CPIL ON CPIL.ID = IL.FKPlaceID
            LEFT JOIN core.Places CPIL2 ON CPIL2.ID = CPIL.FKParentID 
            LEFT JOIN institute.LocationAddresses ILE ON ILE.ID = IL.FKVisitingAddressID
            LEFT JOIN core.Places CP ON CP.ID = EE.FKPlaceID
            INNER JOIN economy.Currencies EC ON EEP.FKCurrencyID = EC.ID
            INNER JOIN education.Educations E ON EE.FKEducationID = E.ID
            LEFT JOIN education.LengthUnits EL ON E.FKLengthUnitID = EL.ID
            INNER JOIN core.EducationTypes CE ON CE.ID = E.FKEducationTypeID
            INNER JOIN institute.Institutes I ON E.FKInstituteID = I.ID
            LEFT JOIN institute.InstituteTextProperties IP ON IP.FKInstituteID = I.ID
            INNER JOIN institute.LocationAddresses ILA ON ILA.ID = I.FKMainAddressID
            INNER JOIN searchIndex.IndexInstitutes II ON I.ID = II.FKInstituteID
            INNER JOIN searchIndex.IndexEducations IE ON E.ID = IE.FKEducationID AND II.FKIndexID = IE.FKIndexID
        WHERE
            II.FKIndexID = @IndexID AND I.IsPublished = 1 AND ESI.Description IS NULL AND (IP.FKTextPropertyID = 1 OR IP.FKTextPropertyID IS NULL)
        ORDER BY I.ID DESC
```

Using Entity framework. Extension:

```
public static class DbContextExtensions
    {
        public static async Task<IReadOnlyList<T>> FromSql<T>(this DbContext context, string sql, params object[] parameters) where T : class
        {
            return await context.Set<T>().FromSql(sql, parameters).AsNoTracking().ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
```

And usage:

```
var data = await _context.FromSql<Model>("Query string", parameter);
```

What would be the best permanent solution for optimizing particular query? Thank you for the answers

Comment: Do you really need to pull back that much data? What do you do with it? Is there any way you can offload more of the work to the db?

Comment: @AdamBenson Yes, I need all the data presented from joined tables

Comment: First pull only the data you need with custom select to an anonymous or DTO. Second don't pull all the rows use lazy loaded enumerable. This will generally use a bit more of processing but will save memory.

Comment: Also switching to Dapper will help in performance and memory consumption if raw sql is all you need